# JavaScript - Can a website see userscript generated errors/console logs?

Tags: javascript, console, syntax-error

Is it possible in any way for websites to detect the usage of userscripts by any errors that the user may experience from that userscript?

Say that a website administrator wants to catch userscripters by changing something in the website that then causes object selectors in the userscripts to fail. Can the website know about the errors caused by a failing userscript and or can they in some way read the console.log()'s created by the userscript?

**This is not a question about DOM modification.**

Brock, this may be your field. :)

Comment: Let's assume the userscripts don't make ANY DOM modifications. If the userscript is merely SELECTING a DOM element, which fails, which outputs an error, can the website see that error and know the userscript failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A website can check their DOM to see if the page has been modified in ways that are not done by their own code.  So, if a userscript was modifying the page in some way, a website could potentially detect that modification (they'd have to be looking for it).

A website can replace `console.log()` with their own function that captures any output sent to it (this would be actual `console.log()` statements in your code, not other messages the system puts in the console (such as uncaught exceptions).

Comment: Okay, so console.log() can be interfered with. Let's assume the userscripts don't make ANY DOM modifications. If the userscript is merely SELECTING a DOM element, which fails, which outputs an error, can the website see that error and know the userscript failed?

Comment: @Edge - If your script is smart, no error will be output anywhere.  You can test to see if a DOM element exists without creating any sort of error.  I don't personally know of any way that one script can see if any other scripts caused any errors, but you'd be better to just not cause any errors in the first place by writing defensive code that tests any DOM query results before using them so as to never cause an error in the first place.  You can also catch any of your own exceptions too so they are never "uncaught exceptions".